# Represent Oracle sql Cube with Microstrategy

Tags: cube, oracle12c, cubes, microstrategy

Hi i have a serveral cube tables on oracle 12c database. How respresent its with Microstrategy? The Object Intelligent Cube the Microstrategy don't represent correctly this cubes and It save in-memory sqls. I need execute sql realtime to cube table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A MicroStrategy cube is an in-memory copy of the results of an SQL query executed against your data warehouse. It's not intended to be a representation of the Oracle cubes.

I assume both these "cubes" organize data in a way that is easy and fast to use for dimensional queries, but I don't think you can import directly an Oracle cube into MicroStrategy IServer memory.

I'm not an expert with Oracle Cubes, but I think you need to map dimensions and facts like you would do with any other Oracle table. At the end an Oracle cube is a tool that Oracle provide to organize your data (once dimensions and metrics are defined) and speed up your query, but you still need to query it: MicroStrategy will write your queries, but also MicroStrategy needs to be aware of your dimensions and metrics (MicroStrategy facts).

At the end the a cube speeds up your queries organizing and aggregating your data, and it seems to me that you have achieved this already with your Oracle cube. A MicroStrategy cube is an in-memory structure that saves also the time required by a query against the database.

Answer (score 1):

If your requirements are that you execute SQL against your database at all times, then you need to disable caching on the MicroStrategy side (this can be done on a report-by-report basis, or at a project level).

MicroStrategy Intelligent Cubes aren't going to be a good fit for you here, because they explicitly cache data, in order to decrease response time, and reduce load on your source database.